# Find the value of $\Vert\nabla f(3,4)\Vert$ if $f(x,y)=\mathrm{distance}((x,y),\overline{B(0,1)})$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\overline{B(0,1)}$, let

$$f(x,y)=\mathrm{distance}((x,y),\overline{B(0,1)})$$

Find the value of $\Vert\nabla f(3,4)\Vert$,
where $\overline{B(0,1)})$ is closed unit disk with center at origin

Regarding my approach to this question I tried my best to solve it using Lagrange's multiplier method but couldn't not solved it,any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Why would you need to use Lagrange multipliers? Can't you just write a formula for $f(x,y)$ and compute the partial derivatives? It seems like $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 1$. So it shouldn't be too hard to compute the derivatives to get the gradient, then plug in $x=3,y=4$ and find the length of that vector.

Comment: How dou you compute the formula for f?

Comment: The closest point on the sphere to $(x,y)$ is clearly the one which lies on the same line through the origin as $(x,y)$. If you draw a picture, it is kind of intuitively obvious. If you want a formal proof that this is the formula, then maybe is this why you were trying to use Lagrange multipliers? If that is the case, maybe you should edit your question, so it is more clear that you are asking how to find a formula for $f$, rather than answering the question about finding $|\nabla f(3,4)|$.

Comment: @Nick thanks a lot its quite clear now